How to make a Navigator with the same destination as BottomNavigationBar?
I want to add a button to 'src/screens/home.dart' that has the same transition as the BottomNavigationBar in 'src/app.dart'. Of course, keeping the AppBar and BottomNavigationBar.
In my code, if I move from the button in home to cam Screen, it leaves app.dart.
It is also plausible that the UI should be reviewed.
After that transition, I want the BottomNavigationBar icon to light up. When moving to a screen with no icons, I want all icons to be dimmed.
Same as the 'app.dart _buildIcon' process.
I started learning Flutter yesterday, so if there's any weird code, please let me know.
Thank you.
enter image description here

Edit:.
I gave HomeScreen() a PageController and was able to take over the AppBar and BottomBar, but the BottomBar selection is not updated.

main.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'src/app.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,]);
  runApp(
    const MyApp()
  );
}

src/app.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'screens/home.dart';
import 'screens/cam.dart';
import 'screens/setting.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      home: BasePage(),
    );
  }
}

class BasePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _BasePage createState() => _BasePage();
}


class _BasePage extends State<BasePage> {
  final _pageController = PageController();
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var TabItem = {
      'home':[0, Icons.home, Colors.green, HomeScreen(pageController: _pageController)],
      'cam':[1, Icons.video_camera_back, Colors.lightGreen, const CamScreen()],
      'setting':[2, Icons.settings, Colors.yellow, const SettingScreen()]
    };

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 16,
        title: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', width: 200, fit: BoxFit.contain,),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),

      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: TabItem.values.map((value) => value[3] as Widget).toList(),
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /8,
        child:BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          selectedFontSize: 0,
          unselectedFontSize: 0,
          items: TabItem.entries.map(
            (tabItem) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _buildIcon(tabItem.value[1] as IconData, tabItem.value[2]as Color, selected: _currentIndex == tabItem.value[0]),
              label: tabItem.key,
            ),
          ).toList(),
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
              _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
            });
          },
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,          
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildIcon(IconData icon, Color color, {bool selected=false}) {
    Color filteredColor = selected ? color : color.withOpacity(0.3); 
    return Container(
      width: 60, height: 60,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: filteredColor),
      child: Icon(icon, size: 50, color: Colors.white,),
    );
  }
}

src/screens/home.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController pageController;
  HomeScreen({super.key, required this.pageController,});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){pageController.jumpToPage(1);},
            child: Container(
              // Omit the code here.
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

src/screens/cam.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CamScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CamScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:
          const Center(child: Text('camera', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0))),
    );
  }
}

SOLVED
src/app.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'screens/home.dart';
import 'screens/cam.dart';
import 'screens/setting.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      home: BasePage(),
    );
  }
}

class BasePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _BasePage createState() => _BasePage();
}

class _BasePage extends State<BasePage> {
  final _pageController = PageController();
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  void changeIndex(index){
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
      _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var TabItem = {
      'home':[0, Icons.home, Colors.green, HomeScreen(pageController: _pageController, changeIndex: changeIndex,)],
      'cam':[1, Icons.video_camera_back, Colors.lightGreen, const CamScreen()],
      'setting':[2, Icons.settings, Colors.yellow, const SettingScreen()]
    };

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 16,
        title: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', width: 200, fit: BoxFit.contain,),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),

      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: TabItem.values.map((value) => value[3] as Widget).toList(),
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /8,
        child:BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          selectedFontSize: 0,
          unselectedFontSize: 0,
          items: TabItem.entries.map(
            (tabItem) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _buildIcon(tabItem.value[1] as IconData, tabItem.value[2]as Color, selected: _currentIndex == tabItem.value[0]),
              label: tabItem.key,
            ),
          ).toList(),
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
              _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
            });
          },
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,          
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildIcon(IconData icon, Color color, {bool selected=false}) {
    Color filteredColor = selected ? color : color.withOpacity(0.3); 
    return Container(
      width: 60, height: 60,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: filteredColor),
      child: Icon(icon, size: 50, color: Colors.white,),
    );
  }
}

src/screens/home.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController pageController;
  final void Function(int) changeIndex;
  const HomeScreen({super.key, required this.pageController, required this.changeIndex});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){changeIndex(1);},
            child: Container(
              // Omit the code here.
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Check out the below code. In your edited code you were handling MyApp widget incorrectly, you need to pass a home widget to MaterialApp.
And you don' need onPageChange here beacuse it is used when you scroll in PageView and want to do some changes on page change but in your case you are manually changing it on bottom navigation bar click
void main()  {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // postData();
    // fetchIPAddress();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: BasePage(),
    );
  }
}

enum TabItem {
  home(
      title: 'home',
      icon: Icons.home,
      color: Colors.green,
      page: HomeScreen()
  ),
  cam(
      title: 'cam',
      icon: Icons.video_camera_back,
      color: Colors.lightGreen,
      page: CamScreen()
  ),
  setting(
      title: 'setting',
      icon: Icons.settings,
      color: Colors.cyan,
      page: SettingScreen()
  );

  const TabItem({
    required this.title,
    required this.icon,
    required this.color,
    required this.page,
  });
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final Color color;
  final Widget page;
}

class BasePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const BasePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<BasePage> createState() => _BasePageState();
}

class _BasePageState extends State<BasePage> {
  final _pageController = PageController();
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 16,
        title: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', width: 200, fit: BoxFit.contain,),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),

      body: Expanded(
        child: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: TabItem.values.map(
                  (tabItem) => tabItem.page
          ).toList(),
        ),
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /8,
        child:BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          selectedFontSize: 0,
          unselectedFontSize: 0,
          items: TabItem.values.map(
                (tabItem) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _buildIcon(tabItem.icon, tabItem.color, selected: _currentIndex==tabItem.index),
              label: tabItem.title,
            ),
          ).toList(),
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
              _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
            });
          },
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildIcon(IconData icon, Color color, {bool selected=false}) {
    Color filteredColor = selected ? color : color.withOpacity(0.3);
    return Container(
      width: 60, height: 60,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: filteredColor),
      child: Icon(icon, size: 50, color: Colors.white,),
    );
  }
}

Edit:
The prblm when you click a btn on HomeScreen and go to other page, remove appbar and bottom nav bar is because you are using Navigator.push(). What you want to do is go from one page to another in pageview then use _pageController.jumpTo(). Just pass the controller to pages, which involve going to other pages.
When you uses Navigator you are changing the whole screen but that's not what we want. We only want to change pages in page view to do that uses pageViewController

Thanks Ultranmus for letting me know.
But with your code, when I press the button I placed in 'home.dart' and go to 'cam.dart', the AppBar and BottomBar disappear. This is not what I want.
Just an idea, but could I pass the _pageController specified in PageView as a parameter, like HomeScreen(_pageController)?

Can you add the homescreen and cam screen code, I tested my code with placeholder. So I guess the prblm is within these widgets

'home.dart' is in the text.' cam.dart' was also added.

i edited the answer check it again. Navigator is only used when you want to change whole screen context. But we only want to change pageview pages to that rather then Navigator.push() uses pageViewController.jumpTo(). Just Passes reference of controller to pageview pages.

Sorry for the late reply.
I was thinking of passing PageController to HomeScreen(). And it worked.
But the selection state of the BottomNavigationBar is not updated. The page is cam but the home icon is glowing (there might be a mistake in _buildIcon).
If you have a solution for this, please let me know. I've put the current code in the questions section.

The reason it is not changing the icon is because you are not updating current index in parent and calling setState for parent that contain bottom nav bar. Let's do this define a callback in parent which update the index and call setState ans pass it to home screen. And when you are using pagecontroller, just use this callback

I could define a callback on '_BasePage' and pass it as an argument to HomeScreen().
ありがとう (meaning thanks in Japanese) @Ultranmus.

Maybe you can give a try to PageView widget.
Just wrap the PageView in a Expanded widget & wrap it with your appbar & bottom tabbar.
To change page, use the page view controller, the animation will be animated (can be disabled of course).
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html

Thanks iStornZ, I'll give it a try.
I just want to use the home.dart button or BottomNavigationBar to navigate, not scroll.
And also to change the color of the icons when moving through the pages. (See attached image.)

You can just give NeverScrollablePhysics() to PageView, it will not scroll then. And on click of bottom navigation bar  when navigating to other tab using pageViewController.animateTo() set its duration to Duration.Zero

Exactly what @Ultranmus said, you can change physics of PageView to NeverScrollablePyshics to disable scrolling. Feel free to change the color of your tab when the user change tab after calling animateTo() :)

Thanks, @iStornZ and @Ultranmus.
I added PageView to 'app.dart' based on your comments. Or is it correct to add it to 'home.dart'?
But still when I press a button in 'home.dart', the AppBar and BottomBar disappear at the destination. I've added the current code to the body of the question, so can you tell me where I'm going wrong?
